# Adding Arrays Index number to labels

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var arr = [];
$('.inp').click(function(){

function arrcall() {
            $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
                alert('Array Key is: ' + key + ' \n Array Key value is: ' + value);
            });
        }

  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  if(value == 'empty') {
    this.value = id + 'ON';
    value = $(this).val();
    arr.push(value);
    arrcall();
    $('.txt').val(arr.join(','));
    return false;
  }
  if(value == id + 'ON') {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1)
    this.value = id + 'OFF';
    value = $(this).val();
    arr.push(value);
    arrcall();
    $('.txt').val(arr.join(','));
    return false;
  }
  if(value == id + 'OFF') {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1)
    this.value = 'empty';
    value = $(this).val();
    arrcall();
    $('.txt').val(arr.join(','));
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class='txt' type='input'>
  
  <label>X</label>
  <input class='inp' id='x' type='button' value='empty'>
  
  <label>Y</label>
  <input class='inp' id='y' type='button' value='empty'>
  
  <label>Z</label>
  <input class='inp' id='z' type='button' value='empty'>
</form>
```

I'm trying here to change the value of the input and add it to the `.txt` input, Now my problem is nubmering the lables by its array key

For example

If i clicked `Z button` then `X button` then `Y button` and turned them to `ON` or `OFF` i want them to have their `index key number + 1` so the label would change to be

```
X-2[xON] Y-3[yON] Z-1[zON]
```

and if i turned one of them to `empty` again, the numbers get ordered correctly again by the index.

so if i made `Z button` `OFF` the buttons would be

```
X-1[xON] Y-2[yON] Z[empty]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this works. What's the meaning of the content of the input? When you remove an item from the array, you do `arr.splice(arr.indexOf(value), 1)` but that's going to eliminate the first appearance of that value in the array, and not the one that is associated to the button that you clicked (is that correct?). To be able to help you, please explain me what you want to have in the array `arr` and what should be shown in the input.

Comment: @A.Iglesias I made it unique with its `id` now, What i want to do is when the button is marked `ON` or `OFF` and has a value in the `.txt` to make his label nubered by its order in the array, so if it is the first, instead of typing its `index key = 0` i make it `1` And if turned it `empty` the value is removed from the array and if all 3 buttons were active the 2nd and 3rd will become 1st and 2nd, And if tried to activate the deactivated button again to make its array become the 3rd.

Comment: OK. I think now I get it. Check my answer when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've loaded the new array, you can loop through all inputs an search its position in the array, to modify the label. Try this...

```
var arr = [];

function arrcall() {
    $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
        alert('Array Key is: ' + key + ' \n Array Key value is: ' + value);
    });
}

$('input.inp').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = this.value;
    var position = arr.indexOf(value);

    if (value == 'empty') {
        this.value = id+'ON';
        arr.push(this.value);
    }
    else if (value == id+'ON') {
        this.value = id+'OFF';
        arr[position] = this.value;
    }
    else if (value == id+'OFF') {
        this.value = 'empty';
        arr.splice(position,1);
    }

    arrcall();

    $('input.txt').val(arr.join(','));

    // Loop through all your inputs, search its value and modify label.        
    $('input.inp').each(function() {
        var pos = 0;
        if ((pos = arr.indexOf($(this).val())) >= 0)
            $(this).prev('label').text($(this).attr('id')+'-'+(pos+1));
        else
            $(this).prev('label').text($(this).attr('id'));
    });

})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It works but there is two problem acquired, If i selected `X` then `Y` i get  `X-1 [xON] Y-2[yON]` but if i clicked again on `X` it acts like a new addition so it becomes `X-2 [xOFF] Y-1[yON]` but i want to keep it as it is, The other problem is when i click on an `OFF` button, Its number is supposed to disappear and reorder the other active buttons, but the number stays.

Comment: But i understood the main idea of the `.each` part.

Comment: I've corrected the second problem. The first on I guess is related to the way you load the array. Just load it as you want, and the last `.each` will take care of the label modification.

Comment: Check the new modification. I think now everything works as you describe. I hope it helps